# Power automate desktop error while using run application

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am using Power Automate desktop.

I run Visual Studio 2017 using run application and I get the following error :

> Can't retrieve main window handle for application

What do I do and how?

Please be specific .

It's 2022 and all the other answers are not up do date

thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information pertaining to your flow and the steps involved.  You're essentially asking us how long a piece of string is.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the parameters to avoid the error. Sometimes the window handle is not resolved after running an application and hence this kind of error can occur if we wait for application to load or complete. In my case I modified the below parameters, and the error was resolved. [Snip of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHzg9.png)